# Как в C# создать отдельный класс для заполнения combobox на многих формах?

Tags: c#, winforms

Смысл в чем имеется несколько форм, на этих формах имеются одинаковые combobox к примеру выберите пол человека. Как сделать что бы считывание данных с БД в combobox происходило в отдельном классе?

Если бы это было в методе формы то код был бы

```
    public static class cb_Drop_down
    {
     public static void Drop_down_cb_sex()
     {
         SqlConnection sqlConnection = new 
 SqlConnection(ConectionSQL_string.sql_string);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        string sql_quiry = $"SELECT Name, id FROM Sex";
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_quiry, 
sqlConnection);
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        this.cb_sex.DataSource = dataTable;
        this.cb_sex.DisplayMember = "Name";// столбец для отображения
        this.cb_sex.ValueMember = "id";//столбец с id
        this.cb_sex.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

но в отдельном классе через this не связать:( что можно использовать в данном случае?

Comment: Сделайте базовый класс для комбобоксов общих, и в потомках дописывайте функционал для отдельных форм.

Comment: @Anamnian т.е. получается программно добавлять combobox на форму, а не через графический интерфейс?

Comment: ну или `public static void Drop_down_cb_sex(Combobox target)` и делайте с ним всё, что хотите внутри функции

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо!!! помогло

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть много способов решения вашей проблемы. 
Как самый простой вариант, вы можете переделать вашу функцию так, чтобы оправлять в неё комбобокс и внутри этот комбобокс готовить как вам надо. Например

```
public static void Drop_down_cb_sex(Combobox target) ....
```